# how select only one box in a choice group

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I only allow a user to select only one checkbox?

I have a field where users need to select one options (yes or no) (one options...mercedes, ford ecc), but not both. there is I need my users to also be able to unselect their option.

if you can also simplify or better reduce the code :)
if you have other ideas write!
thank you all

```css
ul,
#myUL1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  color: black;
}

#myUL1 {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.box30 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box20 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box40 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box30::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.box20::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.box40::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.check-box30::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.check-box20::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.check-box40::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.nested30 {
  display: none;
}

.nested40 {
  display: none;
}

.nested20 {
  display: none;
}

.active30 {
  display: block;
}

.active20 {
  display: block;
}

.active40 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <h50> have a car?</h50>
  <br />
  <span class="box20">yes</span> <span class="box30">No</span>
  <ul class="nested30&#9;">
    <li>
      <h50>ops!</h50>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nested20">
    <li>do you want alloy wheels?</li>
    <span class="box20">yes</span> <span class="box30">No</span>
    <ul class="nested30">
      <li>ops!<br />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nested20">
      <li>Which brand?</li>
      <span class="box20">honda </span><br />
      <ul class="nested20">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="box30">renault</span><br />
      <ul class="nested30">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="box40">fiat</span> <br />
      <ul class="nested40">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
<script>
  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box30");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested30").classList.toggle("active30");
      this.classList.toggle("check-box30");
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box20");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested20").classList.toggle("active20");
      this.classList.toggle("check-box20");
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box40");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested40").classList.toggle("active40");
      this.classList.toggle("check-box40");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `radio` button instead of custom implementation.

Comment: I'm not an expert at this, could you help me?

Comment: You don’t need to be an “expert” to be able to type “html radio button” or similar into the search engine of your choice. Please make a basic effort to inform yourself if you encounter something that is new to you.

Comment: Before writing here I created this code, but I was offered radio button, but I tried to search on the search engine but I can not find anything that can help me with javascript .. sorry but I am at the beginning, I just need an example to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me start by this

> The expert in anything was once a beginner

The perfect and practical way to do this is by using radio buttons instead of checkboxs.

I found an example on the internet that can help you with radio buttons :) 
https://codepen.io/dhanushbadge/pen/kICBu

However , i corrected your example to make it work like you wanted just to show how much it is complicated. Because every time you check a checkbox , you need to uncheck the others ones.

I only modified your javascript code.

I hope this helps you

```css
ul,
#myUL1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  color: black;
}

#myUL1 {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.box30 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box20 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box40 {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  color: blue;
}

.box30::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.box20::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.box40::before {
  content: "\2610";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: blue;
}

.check-box30::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.check-box20::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.check-box40::before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: blue;
}

.nested30 {
  display: none;
}

.nested40 {
  display: none;
}

.nested20 {
  display: none;
}

.active30 {
  display: block;
}

.active20 {
  display: block;
}

.active40 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <h50> have a car?</h50>
  <br />
  <span class="box20">yes</span> <span class="box30">No</span>
  <ul class="nested30&#9;">
    <li>
      <h50>ops!</h50>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nested20">
    <li>do you want alloy wheels?</li>
    <span class="box20">yes</span> <span class="box30">No</span>
    <ul class="nested30">
      <li>ops!<br />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nested20">
      <li>Which brand?</li>
      <span class="box20">honda </span><br />
      <ul class="nested20">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="box30">renault</span><br />
      <ul class="nested30">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="box40">fiat</span> <br />
      <ul class="nested40">
        <li>
          <h50>good choice</h50>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
<script>

function toggleBox20(toggler) {
      toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".nested20").classList.toggle("active20");
      toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".box20").classList.toggle("check-box20");
}

function toggleBox30(toggler) {
      toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".nested30").classList.toggle("active30");
      toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".box30").classList.toggle("check-box30");
}

function toggleBox40(toggler) {
   toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".nested40").classList.toggle("active40");
      toggler.parentElement.querySelector(".box40").classList.toggle("check-box40");
}

  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box30");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggleBox30(this);
   
   //Uncheck Box20
   if(this.parentElement.querySelector(".box20").classList.contains( "check-box20" )) {
   toggleBox20(this);
   }
   
   //Uncheck Box40
   var box40 = this.parentElement.querySelector(":scope > .box40") ;
   var nestedBox40 = this.parentElement.querySelector(":scope > .nested40") ;
   if(box40 != null  && box40.classList.contains( "check-box40" )) {
     toggleBox40(box40);
   }
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box20");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      toggleBox20(this);
   
   //Uncheck Box30 if it s checked
   if(this.parentElement.querySelector(".box30").classList.contains( "check-box30" )) {
   toggleBox30(this);
   }
   
   //Uncheck Box40 if it s checked
   var box40 = this.parentElement.querySelector(":scope > .box40") ;
   var nestedBox40 = this.parentElement.querySelector(":scope > .nested40") ;
   if(box40 != null  && box40.classList.contains( "check-box40" )) {
     toggleBox40(box40);
   }
    });
  }
</script>
<script>
  var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("box40");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
    toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      toggleBox40(this);
   
   if(this.parentElement.querySelector(".box30").classList.contains( "check-box30" )) {
   toggleBox30(this);
   }
   
   if(this.parentElement.querySelector(".box20").classList.contains( "check-box20" )) {
   toggleBox20(this);
   }
    });
 
 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much !! it was just what I was trying to do with the code but I couldn't get it to work!
great!

Answer (score 1):

You could instead make use of radio button like this,

```html
<ul id="myUL">
    <h50> have a car?</h50>
    <br />
    <label for="huey">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="Yes">
    <label for="huey">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="No">
</ul>
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give me a practical example like mine? I then personalize it!
thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: The practical example is what you see :p

Comment: yes you are right but i don't understand and i'm trying it inserting also java and css but i'm not working :(